# Using Promise in structural directive created infinite loop

Tags: angular, promise, observable, angular2-directives

I am working on an Angular 2.4.x application. I implemented a structural directive to display the host element if the expression evaluates to true. The directive is executing infinitely causing the browser to crash.

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: '[wpHasAnyPermission]'
})
export class HasAnyPermissionDirective {

    private authorities: Authority[];

    constructor(private principal: Principal, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    }

    @Input()
    set wpHasAnyPermission(value: Authority[]) {
        this.authorities = <Authority[]> value;
        this.updateView();
        // TODO: Get notified each time authentication state changes.
        // this.principal.getAuthenticationState().subscribe((identity) => this.updateView());
    }

    private updateView(): void {
        console.log("Updating view: " + JSON.stringify(this.authorities));
        this.principal.hasAnyPermission(this.authorities).then((result) => {
            console.log("Inside subscription: " + result);
            this.viewContainerRef.clear();
            if (result) {
                this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`hasAnyPermission`

```
hasAnyPermission(permissions: Authority[]): Promise<boolean> {
    return Promise.resolve(this.hasAnyPermissionDirect(permissions));
}
```

Note that I am using an is array of 'Authority' as input. When I change `hasAnyPermission` to return an observable, the application works as expected and does not go into an infinite loop.

new `hasAnyPermission`

```
hasAnyPermission(permissions: Authority[]): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.of(this.hasAnyPermissionDirect(permissions));
}
```

`updateView` now subscribes like below

```
this.principal.hasAnyPermission(this.authorities).subscribe((result) => {
```

If it helps, following is the component HTML in which I call the directive

```html
<li routerLinkActive="active"
    *wpHasAnyPermission="[authority(permEnum.USER_CREATE, permLevel.ACCOUNT_OWN)]">
    <a id="createUser" routerLink="users/create">
        <i class="icon-plus-circle2"></i>Create a New User
    </a>
</li>
```

Following is a snippet from component on `authority()`, `permEnum` and `permLevel` which are Enums. `Authority` is a POJO.

```
permEnum = PermissionType;
permLevel = PermissionLevel;

authority(perm: PermissionType, level: PermissionLevel): Authority {
    return Authority.of(perm, level);
}
```

Why is this happening with promise but not observable?